# PASAR UNA VARIABLE A UN MODAL

Tags: php, javascript, html, bootstrap, modal

Hola lo que deseo es básicamente pasar una variable a un modal, el icono para abrir el modal esta en cada linea de una tabla es decir, cada linea tiene su propio id y demás datos. Deseo extraer datos de la base de datos dentro del código del modal a partir de la variable que se pase y presentar los datos en el mismo modal en una tabla.

```
 <td HEIGHT="1"><span class="pull-right">
     <a href="#" id="detalle_examen"  title='detalle_examen'  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_detalle_examen"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Ver detalles</a> 
</span></td> 



<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal_detalle_examen" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:1300px;" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i> Ver Registro</h4>
      </div>
        <?php
           $sql="select id,codigo_as400, etc from table where id='".$ID_enviado."';
           $query = pg_query($db3, $sql);
        ?>
     ###############
     Aqui en una tabla el resultado de la consulta
    ############
```

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar.

Comment: Necesitas usar ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear un archivo a parte php para que lo mandes a consultar por medio de ajax y devolver los datos en formato json y mostrarlos con javascript

```
<script>
    function getData(id) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { id: id },
            success: function (data) {
                // data tiene los datos de la consulta en json para mostrar
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // Display error
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<td HEIGHT="1">
    <span class="pull-right">
        <a href="#" id="detalle_examen" onclick="getData('aqui el id a consultar')"  title='detalle_examen'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Ver detalles</a> 
    </span>
</td>

// ajax.php
<?php
$id = intval($_POST['id']);
$sql="select id,codigo_as400, etc from table where id='".$id."';
$result = pg_query($db3, $sql);
$myarray = array()
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
  $myarray[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($myarray);
?>
```